# How to create a ListView with AlertDialog.Builder onItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog, onitemclicklistener

I have a problem with adding AlertDialog.Builder with ListView and onItemClickListener...how to do it? Can you give an example of code

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far? "I have a problem" is pretty abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  private void AlertDialogView() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowDialog.this);//ERROR ShowDialog cannot be resolved to a type
    builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView and Radio button");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: `//ERROR ShowDialog cannot be resolved to a type` is pretty misleading.

Comment: ShowDialog.this seems to be the activity class in which AlertDialogView() is called. I used getApplicationContext() at first, which does not work. So you need to give the context like suggested in this answer <ActivityClass>.this

Answer (score -1):

Considering `listView` is your ListView and `MainActivity` is the name of your Activity.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Position clicked: " + position)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
});
```